# Kendo Grid Server Side Paging With Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I have a kendo grid in my partial view.

And I have binded a model as the grid data source. And mention that my grid don't have a **Read**  method. Instead of read method I have use the model.

Here is my view..

```
@model Project.MVC.Areas.Razor.Models.CustomerListModel

<div id="dvResultGrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.Application.BoundedContext.ScreenPop.Dtos.Customer>(Model.CustomerList)
    .Name("grdWindowResults")

    .Columns(columns =>
                   {
                       columns.Bound(x => x.Name1).Visible(true);
                       columns.Bound(x => x.Name2).Visible(true);
                       columns.Bound(x => x.ContactName);
                       columns.Bound(x => x.BillingAddress1);
                   })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable(x => x.Enabled(false))
    .Scrollable(x => x.Height("auto"))
    .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)                                                              
        .PageSize(5)
        .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(p => p.CustomerId);

                })
    )
)
</div>
```

And what I have to do is, I need to do serverside paging for my grid.
How can I do that with out a read method. Is there any option?

Comment: If you are binding the grid to a model are you expecting to see more results that aren't part of the expected result set to be materialised? If you are then you will need to include a read action and just change the partial to reference some sort of id to pull back the info you need. Why is it you need to do server side paging as opposed to client side. It's just so that I can understand your use case